# VBA Loop: if cell contains specific value then delete the row containing the value and the next 3 rows below

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I am trying to loop through a long report that removes deletions.

The general logic would be this: if the script finds the value "DELETE" in the column B1 then it should delete the range "A1:I4". I have the below script which obviously doesn't work. I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for a range across multiple columns using the "X" variable. Any help would be appreciated!

I have the following loop:

```
Sub RemoveDel()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To lastrow

    If Range("B" & x).Value = "DELETE" Then Range("A" & x:"I" & x + 4)).ClearContents

     Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What is your **exact** problem? Right now is hard to help you with the information provided.... Please clarify!

Comment: I get "syntax error" when trying to run the above loop. I am fairly sure the syntax is wrong (after "Then") but I cannot figure out how to use the right syntax with the "x" variable added.

Comment: Check your parenthesis as well.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am trying to select Range("A1:I4") but using 1 as an "x" variable, and 4 as an x+3 variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just to fix this part and put the colon in the quotes.

```
If Range("B" & x).Value = "DELETE" Then Range("A" & x & ":I" & x + 4)).ClearContents
```

**EDIT**

You may also use "Cell" rather than Range for the first bit.

```
If Cells(x,"B").Value = .....
```

This works for me:

```
Sub RemoveDel()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To lastrow

    If Range("B" & x).Value = "DELETE" Then Range("A" & x & ":I" & x + 4).ClearContents

Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I never knew you could use column letters for the column input on `Cells(row,col)`! Learn something new every day.

Comment: The first bit works right imo its the part after "Then" that doesn't work. Unfortunately I get syntax error likewise when trying your version.

Comment: Just noticed it looks like there is an extra ) at the end before .ClearContents. Try removing that real quick.

Comment: Yep that worked, I would've never figured out the correct syntax by myself. I am taking note of this. Thank you for the help!